# How to serve Redis key with Nginx?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, redis, nginx-config

I have all my JSON files located in Redis cache.

I want to get it served through Nginx.

```
    # redis-cli -h redis-master
    redis-master:6379> get "zips/80202.json"
       "{\"zipCode\":\"80202\",\"City\":\"DENVER\",\"StateCode\":\"CO\"}"
```

I would like to request the url to be like,

```
http://nginx-host/zips/80202.json
```

where `nginx-host` and `redis-master` are the services in Kubernetes.

expecting response with,

```
{"zipCode":"80202","City":"DENVER","StateCode":"CO"}
```

I am not finding a clear idea on how to configure Nginx. I am running with Kubernetes containers, so services are local with no authentication required to the Redis servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the nginx configuration used to serve with redis key,

```
resolver local=on ipv6=off;

server {
    listen 9000;

    location / {

        set $target '';
        access_by_lua '
            local key = ngx.var.request_uri
            if not key then
                ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "no key requested")
                return ngx.exit(400)
            end

            local redis = require "resty.redis"
            local red = redis:new()

            red:set_timeout(1000) -- 1 second

            local ok, err = red:connect("redis-master.default.svc.cluster.local", 6379)
            if not ok then
                ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "failed to connect to redis: ", err)
                return ngx.exit(500)
            end

            local value, err = red:get(key)

            if not value then
                ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "failed to get redis key: ", err)
                ngx.status = 500
                ngx.say("Something not right")
                return ngx.exit(ngx.OK)
            end

            if value == ngx.null then
                ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "no host found for key ", key)
                ngx.status = 404
                ngx.say("Not found")
                return ngx.exit(ngx.OK)
            end

            if value then
                ngx.say(value)
                return
            end

            ngx.var.target = http
        ';

        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To serve redis data (key:value) pairs via Nginx, you will need the following:

1. A redis client, for instance,
   https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis. This client will help
   retrieve data from redis. You will have to NodeJs Express to give you the API layer
2. You will have to create a service, which  will have to be exposed
   via the ingress controller (if you want to access it from outside
   your K8s cluster
3. Nginx ingress controller configuration to route the requests to this service

Comment: nginx has a module to integrate with redis, no need to do any layer of code to pull data from redis. https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/redis2/ .  I have tried few different configuration and they don't work.

Comment: looks like json conversion is a To-do item for redis2 project.

Comment: Over http all responses you send will go as a stream / string, not as json objects. Based on the content type, the client converts the data to their respective object. http itself is content agnostic.